# How can I make a Mojolicious::Lite static file downloader?

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I'm trying to make a file upload/downloader with Mojolicious::Lite and while the upload section is no problem the download section is causing trouble. This code will let me download small text files but anything else turns into a 0 byte file. Any advice on how to do this right?

```
get '/download/:file' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $file = $self->param('file');
    $self->res->headers->content_type("application/x-download");
    $self->res->content->asset(Mojo::Asset::File->new(path => "./testdir/$file"));
    $self->rendered;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You can install the plugin [Mojolicious::Plugin::RenderFile](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aRenderFile) to make this easy.

```
plugin 'RenderFile';

get '/download/:file' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $file = $self->param('file');
  $self->render_file('filepath' => "./testdir/$file");
};
```

Answer (score 4):

[Joel Berger posted this little program to start a web server to serve local files](http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2013/01/a-quick-static-file-webserver.html), and it works great:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

@ARGV = qw(daemon);

use Cwd;
app->static->paths->[0] = getcwd;

any '/' => sub {
    shift->render_static('index.html');
    };

app->start;
```